# YouTube API Video Feed Description

Tags: javascript, api, video, youtube, feed

Alright, I have been looking off and on for almost a year now (spent all of March trying to do this), and I simply CAN NOT find the code to make this work.

Here's my problem:

I have a code that retrieves my most recent upload for the player on my website (http://weapwn.com). This code only gives me the video, though.
I need code to get the description - not from any one video ID, but from the variable video ID - but all I have is this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showMyVideos2(data) {
      var feed = data.feed;
      var entries = feed.entry || [];
      var html = ['<ul>'];
      for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = entries[i];
        var content = entry.content.$t;
        html.push('<i>', content, '</i>');
      }
      html.push('</ul>');
      document.getElementById('featdesc').innerHTML = html.join('');
    }
    </script>
```

Now - replacing "content" does nothing, unless I use "title" (which only retrieves the video title). I must know how to get this damn elusive code to work, because the parameters that Youtube lists are not working!

Am I going about this entirely the wrong way? Or is there simply an error to fix in my code?

Comment: Where is the feed coming from and what is its URL?

Comment: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/WeaPwNGaMiNG/uploads?alt=json-in-script&format=5&max-results=1&callback=showMyVideos2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function showMyVideos2(data) {
  var feed = data.feed;
  var entries = feed.entry || [];
  var html = ['<ul>'];
  for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = entries[i];
    var title = entry.title.$t;
    var description = entry.media$group.media$description.$t.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
    var content = entry.content.$t;
    html.push('<i>', content, '</i>','<i>', title, '</i>','<i>', description, '</i>');
  }
  html.push('</ul>');
  document.getElementById('featdesc').innerHTML = html.join('');
}
```

Hope it helps...